# use awk to calculate percentage of column 1 derived from column 2 and add it to column 3

Tags: awk, percentage, calculated-columns

I have a file consisting out of 2 columns, both contain only whole numbers. I want awk to add a third column which shows the percentage of column 1, derived from column 2.

So, for example, column 1 shows:

```
cat file
15      150
```

I want awk to add column 3 to show `10` (because `15` is `10%` of `150`, right?) like this:

```
15      150     10
```

The columns are separated by tabs.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please show some sample file and some sample desired output. Also, as you tag with `awk`, you may have written something so far. Share it so we can see how close you are with the solution.

Comment: This is simple math and simple calculation.  What have you done to try to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another awk

```
awk '$3=100*$1/$2' file
```

To overwrite file

```
awk '$3=100*$1/$2' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If for some reason you have 0s in your file

```
awk '$2>0{$3=100*$1/$2}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

or

```
awk '$2>0&&$3=100*$1/$2' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: @jaypal OH NO! Fixed it now. Sorry about your keyboard :(

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but an educated guess at what might work:

```
awk '{ print $1, $2, 100*$1/$2 }' yourfile.txt
```

To save it to somewhere, you'll have to redirect ´stdout` to a file. If you want this to overwrite your original file (don't do this until you've tested that it works!) you could wrap it in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{ print $1, $2, 100*$1/$2 }' "$1" > "$1.tmp"
mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

and run it like

```
./thebashscript.sh yourfile.txt
```

Comment: You might want to read more at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-and-why-to-do-math-with-awk/

Comment: No need for `-F'\t'`, since any space is default for `awk`

Comment: @Jotne: Thänks, I wasn't sure - and sitting on a Windows machine without any bash emulator atm, I couldn't test it properly.